# A servlet that was working before with certificate authentication was changed and is now throwing exceptions

Tags: java, servlets

A Java servlet application has been changed so that it no longer requires certificate authentication.
That part works correctly. However, the application no longer connects to the database and throws the following exception:

```
> REMOTE USER IS null MY URL is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 NULL GENERICPRINCIPAL
> Apr 01, 2021 12:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
> invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
> [com.harris.cpd.resource.ApplicationConfig] in context with path
> [/cpd] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root
> cause java.lang.NullPointerException  at
> com.harris.cpd.resource.CPDResource.getTomcatUserRole(CPDResource.java:116)
```

The following is web.xml with changes shown in comments.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
        <display-name>cpd</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>chemicals.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    
    <!-- THIS IS NEW CODE -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>CPDAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.harris.cpd.filter.CPDAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CPDAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
     
        
    <!--  THIS SECTION IS NEW CODE -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>cpd</servlet-name>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>cpd</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/cpd/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
      
<!-- THIS SECTION IS NOW COMMENTED OUT
        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>BasicSecurity</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
                <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
                <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <description>Authorized role is librarian</description>
                <role-name>DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>BasicSecurity</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>PUT</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
                <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <description>Authorized role is guest and librarian</description>
                <role-name>DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN</role-name>
                <role-name>DOMAIN_GUEST</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint> -->
        
    <!-- THIS IS NEW CODE AND PROVIDES THE BASIC LOGIN -->
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            <realm-name>Login</realm-name>
        </login-config>
    
<!-- THIS CODE IS NOW COMMENTED OUT
        <login-config>
          <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
          <realm-name>IAASecurityRealm</realm-name>
       </login-config> -->
    
      
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>DOMAIN_GUEST</role-name>
      </security-role>
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN</role-name>
      </security-role>
     
     <!--  
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>GUEST</role-name>
      </security-role>
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>LIBRARIAN</role-name>
      </security-role>
    -->
    
    </web-app>
```

And here is CPDAuthenticationFilter.java which is the filter code.
One line was deleted below:
UserRole role = auth.authenticate(authCredentials);
The following line replaced it, hard-coding "role":
UserRole role = UserRole.DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN;

```
package com.harris.cpd.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.harris.cpd.authentication.AuthenticationService;
import com.harris.cpd.authentication.UserRole;


    //@WebFilter(filterName="authentication", urlPatterns="/resources/*")
    public class CPDAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
        private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CPDAuthenticationFilter.class.getPackage().getName());
        public static final String AUTHENTICATION_ATTR = "cpd.authenticate";
        public static final String USER_ROLE_ATTR = "cpd.user.role";
    
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see javax.servlet.Filter#destroy()
         */
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see javax.servlet.Filter#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)
         */
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filter)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                if (httpServletRequest.isUserInRole(UserRole.DOMAIN_GUEST.toString())) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "found a guest user");
                }
                else if (httpServletRequest.isUserInRole(UserRole.DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN.toString())) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "found a domain_librarian user");
                }
                else {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "found invalid user: "+httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser());
                }
                String authCredentials = httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_ATTR);
    
                AuthenticationService auth = new AuthenticationService();
                // CRM :  TEST access 8080 without login:
                //UserRole role = auth.authenticate(authCredentials);
                UserRole role = UserRole.DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN;  //CGN 3-25 TURNING OFF WHAT CHRIS HAD
    
    
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "user role: " + role);
    
                if (role.equals(UserRole.DOMAIN_GUEST) || role.equals(UserRole.DOMAIN_LIBRARIAN)) {
                    request.setAttribute(USER_ROLE_ATTR, role);
                    filter.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                        logger.log(Level.INFO, "failed BASIC authentication");
                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see javax.servlet.Filter#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig)
         */
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
            System.out.println("init the authentication filter (RestAuthenticationFilter)");
        }
    
    }
```

The errors that shows up on the Chrome debug tools for the client side:

```
-- LOADING APP (index.html) --
:8080/cpd/resources/categories:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
angular.js:14516 -- db: getProcessCategories url:http://localhost:8080/cpd/resources/categories procCats 500  failed --
```

So the problem presents itself as servlet error, and the database is not connecting, returning anything, with just the changes I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think this exception was related to database connection.*
according to the exception which you have faced.
**getTomcatUserRole(CPDResource.java:116)**

I think there is another class like CPDResource.java that has been affected by this change

```
  <!--  
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>GUEST</role-name>
      </security-role>
      <security-role>
        <description>A Guest User in the system</description>
        <role-name>LIBRARIAN</role-name>
      </security-role>
    -->
```

and you should set it as a hardcode instead of getting from roles as before.